# What are the real-life use cases for for fractional/quotient regular languages?

Tags: cs-theory

In computer science theory some textbooks introduce fractional/quotient regular languages. In particular, given L1 and L2 languages on the same alphabet, the right quotient of L1 with L2 is defined as

L1/L2 = {x : xy ∈ L1 for some y ∈ L2}.

The left quotient is defined in a similar way. I was wondering if there are some real-life cases in which quotient languages can be useful. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean " L1 and L2  are _regular_ languages on the same alphabet". I haven't seen the concept before. Which textbook(s). Hopefully plural. I'd expect the book author(s) to give some reasonable examples.

Comment: @Buffy, the definition makes sense for all languages, not just regular ones. And proving that such constructions give regular languages if $L1$ and $L2$ are regular is a popular exercise.